SwiftUI NavigationStack with a shared, stationary background image
Is it possible to have views push and pop from a NavigationStack without their background image also sliding in/out?
The affect I'm trying to achieve is a stationary background image behind the entire stack while only the view's contents would slide in and out while the background remains still and visible.
This is the effect I'd like to achieve, without dipping into UIKit if possible: (Gif taken from this SO question Push ViewController with transparent background)


what have you tried? Did you try adding a background image behind the NavigationStack using for example ZStack?

Yes, yet each view has a white background, even when setting .background(Color.clear) inside of body.
I'm hoping not to have to have to dip into UIKit to remove the white background from each hosting view controller. Looking for a pure SwiftUI solution, if possible.

can you please provide a minimal example of what you tried?
